# mysql copy data to another table and mark as transfered

Tags: mysql, insert, copy

I want to transfer data from table TB to table TA which was entered before today and mark the copied ones as "copied" in TA by. The whole thing has to happen by a routine. My actual code is

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
    `TA` (
        `a`,
        `b`,
        `c`,
    ) 
SELECT 
    `a`,
    `b`,
    `somedate`
FROM 
    `TB`
WHERE 
    `somedate`<NOW()        

UPDATE 
    `TB`
SET `status`='copied'
WHERE 
    `somedate`<NOW();

END
```

So I have two "queries" (is this named correct? - I am quite new to mysql). Is there a more elegant way to to this? Maybe also one which is bulletproof in the sense that "nothing can happen" between the two statements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't do before today, you do before NOW() which means NOW

Comment: The syntax seems fine. It should work. As for elegant ways, the use of INSERT...SELECT statements is the most preferred one if you are trying to replicate tabular data. Check this link from MySQL's official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Add a ";" at the end of your INSERT...SELECT statement after WHERE 'somedate'<NOW(), as it won't work until there's a terminator.

Comment: Well - actual code is something more complicated. This is a reduced version to get the point. Question is if there is some kind of reply from the first query where the second one (set status) explicitly can rely on or if there is a possibility to to the whole action within one query to rule out possible events regardign the data between the statements. Thanks so far!

Comment: You can use a transaction with BEGIN .. COMMIT, but there are issues with MyISAM tables and MySQL Server replication.

Comment: @Adder: Is a transaction the same as a routine or something completly different?

Comment: Ok - I used it as above. Seems fine. Thank you!